# overlays no longer cumulative with seminar document class

Tags: pstricks, overlays

I've been using the seminar document class for years, and have lots of legacy LaTeX using it. But I find that cumulative overlays no longer work properly, at least not with the version (TeX Live 2016/MacPorts 2016_1) of texlive that MacPorts provides. The following is a minimal example, the LaTeX log is below, and [here](http://alleystoughton.us/tmp/foo.pdf) is the result of running LaTeX (and then dvips and ps2pdf) on the example.

I have seen references to seminar not being compatible with recent versions of pstricks. Any suggestions gratefully accepted!

```
\documentclass{seminar}

\usepackage{semcolor}
\usepackage{semlayer}

\input{seminar.bug}
\input{seminar.bg2}

\renewcommand{\printlandscape}{\special{landscape}}

\SeminarAltCumulativeOverlays

\begin{document}
\begin{slide}
Zero {\overlay{1} One} {\overlay{2} Two} {\overlay{3} Three}.
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Here is the LaTeX log:

```
$ latex foo
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/MacPorts 2016_1) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 47 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/seminar/seminar.cls
Document Class: seminar 2014/01/17, 1.61
Documentclass: `seminar' v1.61 <2014/01/17> (tvz,hv)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pst-ovl/pst-ovl.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/pst-ovl/pst-ovl.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.cod
e.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.t
ex) (/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
) (/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetic
s.code.tex)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)))
`PSTricks' v2.66  <2016/05/18> (tvz)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
`pst-ovl' v0.07, 2016/05/03 (tvz,hv)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/seminar/sem-page.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/seminar/semcolor.sty
Style Option: `semcolor' for doc style `seminar' 1.02 <2014/01/17> (tvz)
) (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/seminar/semlayer.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/seminar/seminar.bug)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/seminar/seminar.bg2
seminar.bg2: various corrections for the Seminar document class
added since seminar.bug and few add-ons for overlays
(Version 2.3 of <2014/05/12> (DG, hv))
)
No file foo.aux.
[1] [1] [1] [1] (./foo.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on foo.dvi (4 pages, 4240 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd recommend not installing TeX Live via MacPorts, but via MacTeX.

Comment: I can confirm that TeX Live 2015 produces the expected output, but TeX Live 2016 doesn't. Apparently a problem with pstricks.

Comment: Thanks, egreg. Is it still possible to download MacTeX 2015. I couldn't find links to older distributions on the MacTeX site.

Comment: The historical CTAN archive should have them. It is available for anonymous FTP at ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic Under ./systems/mactex you find MacTeX from 2005 on as compressed tarballs.